# Without the use of a calculator, how to calculate the logarithm of 2 and 3 in base 10

Tags: algorithms

Without the use of calculator how to calculate $\log_{10} ~2$, $\log_{10} ~3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the note

N. David Mermin: Logarithms!, *Am. J. Phys.* **46** (1978), 101-105 
(http://dx.doi.org/10.1119/1.11104).